# Font Face make many requests to download same font

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I'm using styled-components in Next.js and I intend import fonts with font-face because I want to use `font-display: swap`.  My problem is that my application is making many requests of the same font.

It's my Styled.components Global Styles component.

```
import { memo } from 'react';
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export default memo(createGlobalStyle`
  * {
    font-family: Montserrat , 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  }

  html, body, #root {
    font-family: Montserrat , 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
 

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-display: swap;
  }


  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
  }


  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
  }
`);
```

My fonts are in `/public`.
In don't know why it's occurring.

I tried:

- Use only one format and use more format
- Use react memo and don't use react memo

Comment: Does it download the font each time or does it load it from the cache?

Comment: My page download the font each time.